# "Sign up or log in" options are not aligned

Tags: bug, design, sign-up

For the non-logged in user, after the answer box the "Sign up or log in" options are available, but the alignment is broken. Can this be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Excellent circle.

Comment: The definition of π right there.

Comment: Where is the alignment broken?

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment about the alignment; it looks like it is (correctly) left aligned. However, I do think it is weird that *log in* is a clickable link, while *Sign up* is not. None of the *Sign up using ...* options is clickable either.

Comment: I duped this to a newer post as it described the problem more clearly.